# check if class is fragment or activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am getting activity names from api (till now I am using activities in project). But now some of them I made fragment.
As now I am starting my activity as

```
Class<?> myClass = Class.forName("com.aksu.emp." + ((com.core.Menu) o)
                        .getActivityName());
Activity activity = (Activity) myClass.newInstance();
ActivityRedirect(activity);
```

How can I check if it is fragment and swap fragment if some activity I has converted to fragment.

Comment: http://www.javatpoint.com/downcasting-with-instanceof-operator

Answer (score 4):

Manually instantiating Activities etc is not a good idea. Assuming your object is in `o`, you should do something like this

```
if (o instanceof Activity) {
    if (o instanceof ActivityA) {
        // go to A
    } else if (o instanceof ActivityB) {
        // go to B
    }
} if (o instanceof Fragment) {
    // do something else
}
```

For the activities you could even simplify that (if you don't need to send specific data through bundles or similar).

```
if (o instanceof Activity) {
    context.startActivity(context, ((Activity) o).class));
}
```

Comment: No. my question is not in that way. I am getting string from api as "com.aksu.emp.notice.List" and it is a class that extends fragment. and other string as "com.aksu.emp.summary.Data"  this class extends activity how can I convert these string to check whether it is fragment or activity.

Comment: I would not fiddle with converting strings to activities and reflection, might be better to use something like `if (apiStr.equals("com.aksu.emp.notice.List)) { //start this activity }`

Comment: so what about 20 activity and some fragment , 20 else if

Answer (score 0):

Use reflection to get parents. Something like this:

```
myClass.class.getSuperclass()
```

So you can find out if a parent is an activity or another class.

Answer (score 0):

problem was to first check if string is a fragment or class then perform respective action. i solved it as.

```
try {
            if (((com.core.Menu) o).getActivityName() != null) {
                Class<?> myClass = Class.forName("com.aksu.emp." + ((com.core.Menu) o)
                        .getActivityName());
                try {
                    Activity activity = (Activity) myClass.newInstance();
                    ActivityRedirect(activity);

                } catch (Exception e) { // its not an activity it could be fragment
                    Fragment fragment = (Fragment) myClass.newInstance();
                    fragmentOrganizer.openFragment(fragment);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {// ooh string is not in correct format for both activity and fragment
            new ExceptionHandler(this).caughtException(e);
        }
```